# Combine vectors into data frame, using vector name as a column

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, data-manipulation

```
library(dplyr)
```

I have a set of vectors:

```
Sp_A <- c("A",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Sp_B <- c("B",9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
Sp_C <- c("C",17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
```

which I have made into a list of vectors:

```
list <- ls(pattern = "Sp_")
```

I want to use this list to loop over each vector in the list and make it into a data frame . I currently do this for one vector using this:

```
A_df <- select(data.frame(rep(Sp_A[1], each = 4), c(Sp_A[c(2,4,6,8)]), c(Sp_A[c(3,5,7,9)])), name = 1, var1 = 2, var2 = 3)
```

I have tried to make this operation into a `for` loop like this:

```
for(i in list) {
    test[i] <- select(A_df <- data.frame(rep(i[1], each = 4),
                      c(i[c(2,4,6,8)]), 
                      c(i[c(3,5,7,9)]), 
                      name = 1, var1 = 2, var2 = 3))
}
```

but to no avail.

I have heard that I might be able to use `apply()` for this sort of thing but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
lapply(list,function(x) data.frame(name=get(x)[1],matrix(get(x)[-1],ncol = 2)))

[[1]]
  name X1 X2
1    A  1  5
2    A  2  6
3    A  3  7
4    A  4  8

[[2]]
  name X1 X2
1    B  9 13
2    B 10 14
3    B 11 15
4    B 12 16

[[3]]
  name X1 X2
1    C 17 21
2    C 18 22
3    C 19 23
4    C 20 24
```

Or a simple for loop to assign the dataframes to objects:

```
for (x in 1:length(list)){
  assign(paste0("test",x),data.frame(name=get(list[x])[1],matrix(get(list[x])[-1],ncol = 2)))
}
```